# How can I get the XMLHttpRequest back after the data loads?

Tags: javascript, get, xmlhttprequest, httpclient

I have a code in which the "onloadend" runs after the "get" task, and the code would work the right way if  "get" ran first. So i need a way to switch them. I must use HttpClient and JavaScript, I cannot use jQuery or anything else.
Here is my full code in CodePen: https://codepen.io/vargaadam19/pen/BaabVbZ?editors=0010

Here is the onloadend:

```
export class HttpClient {
    constructor(url) {
        this.url = url;
        this.xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        this.xhr.onloadend = (event) => {
            return this.xhr.result;
        };
    }
```

I set header here:

```
 setHeader() {
        this.xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
    }
```

and here is the get function:

```
get(async, header) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.xhr.open('GET', this.url, async);
        this.xhr.setRequestHeader(header.name, header.value);
        this.xhr.send();
        resolve(this.xhr.response);`enter code here`
    });
}
```

And here is the function that's what I invite the get function

```
getAll() {
    this.httpClient.get(true, this.header).then((result) => {
        const data = !!result ? result : '[]';
        const items = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log('result:', result);
        items.forEach(item => {
            const todo = new Todo(item.id, item.name, item.status);
            this.items.push(todo);
        });
    });
}
```

How can I solve this problem about the order of the tasks?

Comment: 1. please write exactly how you declared **get()* and **getAll()** functions, e.g. **var getAll = function(){}**. 2. add example of an input, and desired output

Comment: https://codepen.io/vargaadam19/pen/BaabVbZ?editors=0010 Here is my full code @besciualex